# Parse getInBackground not Working (User Querying with ObjectID)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am currently working on the User Profile part of my app and I would like to run a query on a specific user object using the objectId of that user. With that query, I hope to get the users info(email, username, hometwown, etc.) from parse and display it on the page.

The parse documentation recommends the getInBackground method like so:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyClass");
 query.getInBackground(myId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
     public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
             objectWasRetrievedSuccessfully(object);
         } else {
             objectRetrievalFailed();
         }
     }
 }
```

Using this I would think I would replace "MyClass" with "User" since I will be searching the user class for the specific Id entered. However, I am getting an exception every time and the query is failing. A copy of my code is below where, as an example, I attempt to extract the "hometown" attribute from the specefic user and set it to display as a textview. mId is equal to the specific object ID of the user passed over from another activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends_profile);

    mHometownField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    mId = getIntent().getStringExtra(ParseConstants.KEY_ID);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    query.getInBackground(mId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                mHometown = parseObject.get(ParseConstants.KEY_HOMETOWN).toString();
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(FriendsProfileActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                        .setMessage(e.getMessage())
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });

    mHometownField.setText(mHometown);

}
```

Comment: any idea how to send push notification to specific user i m passing installation objectid but still failed to recieve its not recieving by target devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very common mistake. The "User" class is an internal class so you have to query it differently:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

Same applies for the "Role" and "Installation" classes.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for clearing that up. I actually was experimenting with ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(); What I was missing is switching ParseQuery.getQuery(0 to ParseUser.getQuery(); Everything seems to be working now!

Comment: @RichLuick  any idea how to save ppointer of User table in installation table using parse.com in android

Comment: @Erum Sorry, not sure how to do that

Comment: @RichLuick  i m trying to send parse push notification to specifc user means i m passing user Pointer in installation table and sending notification but its not sending to specific user